# Changing directory in Google colab (breaking out of the python interpreter)

Tags: google-colaboratory

So I'm trying to git clone and cd into that directory using Google collab  - but I cant cd into it. What am I doing wrong?

> !rm -rf SwitchFrequencyAnalysis && git clone https://github.com/ACECentre/SwitchFrequencyAnalysis.git
>
> !cd SwitchFrequencyAnalysis
>
> !ls
> datalab/  SwitchFrequencyAnalysis/

You would expect it to output the directory contents of SwitchFrequencyAnalysis - but instead its the root. I'm feeling I'm missing something obvious - Is it something to do with being within the python interpreter? (where is the documentation??)

[Demo here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13zTMSRipeLewfpVS5k4O5fMuebagqO5o/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Bob Smith's answer below is the right way to go, but if you're curious why the approach above didn't work: the issue is that each of the `!`-prefixed commands runs in its own subshell -- so the `!cd` starts a new shell, switches directories, and then kills that shell. The `!ls` then starts anew in the current directory.

Doing `!cd SwitchFrequencyAnalysis && ls` would have worked, but using python's `os.chdir` is the cleaner approach here.

Answer (score 221):

use

`%cd SwitchFrequencyAnalysis`

to change the current working directory for the notebook environment (and not just the subshell that runs your ! command).

you can confirm it worked with the `pwd` command like this:

`!pwd`

further information about jupyter / ipython magics:
http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd

Comment: Why cd using % while pwd using ! as its prefix

Comment: @cloudscomputes As mentioned by other comments, there is a difference between `!` and `%` such that let's say commands initiating with `!` are global and run for the whole system, while commands with `%` are specific to the current environment (main environment vs a virtual environment for current project). Thus, the `cd` command should be started by `%` to tell the compiler that we are changing the directory for the current temporary subshell.

Answer (score 140):

As others have pointed out, the `cd` command needs to start with a percentage sign:

```
%cd SwitchFrequencyAnalysis
```

### Difference between `%` and `!`

Google Colab seems to inherit these syntaxes from Jupyter (which inherits them from IPython).
Jake VanderPlas explains this IPython behaviour [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Shell-Related-Magic-Commands). You can see the excerpt below.

> If you play with IPython's shell commands for a while, you might
>   notice that you **cannot** use `!cd` to navigate the filesystem:
>
> ```
> In [11]: !pwd 
> /home/jake/projects/myproject
>
> In [12]: !cd ..
>
> In [13]: !pwd 
> /home/jake/projects/myproject
> ```
>
> The reason is that
>   shell commands in the notebook are executed in a temporary subshell.
>   If you'd like to change the working directory in a more enduring way,
>   you can use the `%cd` magic command:
>
> ```
> In [14]: %cd ..
> /home/jake/projects
> ```

Another way to look at this: you need `%` because changing directory is relevant to the environment of the current notebook but not to the entire server runtime.

In general, use `!` if the command is one that's okay to run in a separate shell. Use `%` if the command needs to be run on the specific notebook.

Comment: You can also just use "cd", without !cd or %cd. What does this do :)? Thanks!

Comment: @Erik As I can see thru google colab's documentation pop-up, `cd` is a pre-defined function that the `%cd` magic command is bound to it. When you type the plain `cd` it brings the function with specific shortcut arguments. Declaring no arguments means going back to the `/root` directory.

Answer (score 48):

Use `os.chdir`. Here's a full example:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1CSPBdmY0TxU038aKscL8YJ3ELgCiGGju

Compactly:

```
!mkdir abc
!echo "file" > abc/123.txt

import os
os.chdir('abc')

# Now the directory 'abc' is the current working directory.
# and will show 123.txt.
!ls
```

Comment: great! so, does `/content` and `/root` points to the same folder location. I mean I have a hard time understanding how the commands in googleColab related to the underlying Linux-VM filesystem. Since either you execute `%cd /content | ls` or `!ls -la | pwd` you will end up seeing `/root/.kaggle` which was created using the command set `!pip install -U -q kaggle` followed by `!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle`, that means `~/` which is home directory is equivalent to `/root` & `/content`, are those

Answer (score 36):

If you want to use the cd or ls functions , you need proper identifiers before the function names ( % and ! respectively)
use %cd and !ls to navigate

.

```
!pwd    # to find the directory you're in ,
%cd ./samplefolder  #if you wanna go into a folder (say samplefolder)
```

or if you wanna go out of the current folder

```
%cd ../
```

and then navigate to the required folder/file accordingly

Comment: could you please point to the source where I can find the above usage? also, I am looking for using pipeline operator `|` as we do use in bash shell scripting, any suggestions in that regards? Also, what the distinction between using `%` or `!`

Comment: !ls doesn't give the directory you're in but the list of subfolders

Comment: @TimotheeW thanks for pointing this out. Since i wrote this answer almost 5 years ago, i don't really remember whether !ls gave some sort of absolute path at that time. But !pwd seems to do the trick now, editing it accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

```
!pwd
import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Data')
!pwd
```

view this answer for detailed explaination
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61636734/11535267

Comment: Will also add that you have to first mount Google Drive in Colab and grant Google Drive File Stream authorization.

Comment: You saved my life.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'd have to mount the Google Drive first before you do anything else.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```