# When I use Google Colaboratory, how to save image, weights in my Google Drive?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I use Google Colaboratory then I want to save output images in my Google Drive or SSD, HHD but its directory is "/content"

```
import os     
print(os.getcwd())
# "/content"
```

so is it possible to change path (HDD, SSD, googledrive)?

Comment: in google Colaboratory, os.chdir("c:/" ) is not working but thanks for your opinion :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To save the weight you can run the following after training.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(session, "data/dm.ckpt")
print('done saving at',save_path)
```

Check the location where the ckpt files were saved.

```
import os
print( os.getcwd() )
print( os.listdir('data') )
```

Finally download the file!

```
from google.colab import files
files.download( "data/dm.ckpt.meta" )
```

Comment: Wc.Did you try uploading weights?

Comment: Remember, it takes time to upload the files to google drive and sometime you may have to wait longer depending on number of files and their size for the change to reflect. Just tested it.

Comment: Isn't this downloading to my own computer, not Drive itself?

Answer (score 71):

You need to mount google drive to your Colab session.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then you can simply write to google drive as you would to a local file system like so:

```
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/file.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('content')
```

Comment: For me, it was `drive.mount('/content/drive')`

Answer (score 17):

One of the other simple methods to save a file to Google Drive I found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64131/how-to-save-dynamic-files-from-colab-to-google-drive) is to use the command `cp` after you mounted the drive.

Here is the code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then use this:

```
!cp -r <CURRENT FILE PATH> <PATH YOU WANT TO SAVE>
```

*Example:*

```
!cp -r './runs/exp0.h5' /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Exp1/
```

Comment: Note that this by default overwrites files if the filename is already used in the target folder.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yes. That's true, but you can use `-i` option to check it before. It can be found in this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm#:~:text=To%20view%20output%20when%20files,%2Di%20(interactive)%20option).

Comment: Thanks - very convenient! But note a bug: you've mounted it on `/content/gdrive`, but copied to `/content/drive`. I assume any subdirectory of `/content/` would work, but you need to change one of them to be consistent. I fixed it to use `/content/gdrive`....

Comment: @nealmcb Thank you for your attention. I saw both of them and both are the same. I use `/drive` typically but the result is the same.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [example on interfacing with external files](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb). The general workflow is to output the file to the cloud environment, then download it.

Let's output the plot from the ["Hello, Colaboratory" example](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#scrollTo=8iU2gnJFItM1)  to a file. I made a copy of the notebook to my Google Drive and ran the following commands:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(20)
y = [x_i + np.random.randn(1) for x_i in x]
a, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
f = plt.figure()
_ = plt.plot(x, y, 'o', np.arange(20), a*np.arange(20)+b, '-')

f.savefig( "test.png")
```

If we list the files in the Google Collaboratory environment, we will see `test.png` among them:

```
import os
print( os.getcwd() )
print( os.listdir() )
# /content
# ['datalab', '.local', '.config', '.forever', '.cache', '.rnd', 'test.png', '.ipython']
```

All that's left to do is download it to my local machine using the example I linked at the beginning on this answer:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download( "test.png" )
```

Finally, if you really need the files on Google Drive instead of your local machine, you can use [the Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) to move the files accordingly.

P.S. If you don't like writing files to `/content`, you can always [create a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298146/changing-directory-in-google-collab-breaking-out-of-the-python-interpreter) and `os.chdir()` into it, but keep in mind that this subdirectory is still local to your cloud environment and requires you to download files as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ipynb, make sure:

1. At the begining of your code, you have:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

2. you save it before plt.show(). For instance, the code to save the sns.heatmap of some dataframe df is as follow:

```
matrix1 = df.corr().round(2)
plt.figure(figsize=(19,16))
sns.heatmap(matrix1, annot=True)
plt.savefig('name_heatmap.png') 
plt.show()

files.download('name_heatmap.png')
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32647023)