# How to save an object (with methods included) in google colab (python)?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have created an object which is compounded by a lot of methods. This object takes a long time to build. My question is if exists a way to save the object in my drive in order to load it in another notebook?

I'm working in google colab (python)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try joblib.pickle

Comment: The built-in `pickle` module allows you to save any Python object to a file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I use Google Colaboratory, how to save image, weights in my Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031798/when-i-use-google-colaboratory-how-to-save-image-weights-in-my-google-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount your google drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

then use joblib:

```
import joblib

joblib.dump(object, 'drive/path/filename')
```

then

```
object = joblib.load('drive/path/filename')
```