# Querying SQLite database file in Google Colab

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, google-colaboratory

```
print ('Files in Drive:')

!ls drive/AI
```

Files in Drive:

```
database.sqlite
Reviews.csv
Untitled0.ipynb
fine_food_reviews.ipynb
Titanic.csv
```

When I run the above code in Google Colab, clearly my sqlite file is present in my drive. But whenever I run some query on this file, it says

```
# using the SQLite Table to read data.
con = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite') 

#filtering only positive and negative reviews i.e. 
# not taking into consideration those reviews with Score=3
filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score !=3",con)
```

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE
>   Score != 3 ': no such table: Reviews

Answer (score 4):

Below you will find code that addresses the `db setup on the Colab VM`, `table creation`, `data insertion` and `data querying`. Execute all code snippets in individual notebook cells.

Note however that this example only shows how to execute the code on a non-persistent Colab VM. If you want to save your database to GDrive you will have to mount your Gdrive first ([source](https://towardsdatascience.com/downloading-datasets-into-google-drive-via-google-colab-bcb1b30b0166)):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

and [navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298146/changing-directory-in-google-colab-breaking-out-of-the-python-interpreter) to the appropriate file directory after.

---

**Step 1: Create DB**

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db')  # You can create a new database by changing the name within the quotes
c = conn.cursor() # The database will be saved in the location where your 'py' file is saved

# Create table - CLIENTS
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE SqliteDb_developers
             ([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [name] text, [email] text, [joining_date] date, [salary] integer)''')

conn.commit()
```

Test whether the DB was created successfully:

```
!ls
```

Output:

> > > sample_data  SQLite_Python.db

---

**Step 2: Insert Data Into DB**

```
import sqlite3

try:
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db')
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")

    sqlite_insert_query = """INSERT INTO SqliteDb_developers
                          (id, name, email, joining_date, salary) 
                           VALUES (1,'Python','MakesYou@Fly.com','2020-01-01',1000)"""


    count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Record inserted successfully into SqliteDb_developers table ", cursor.rowcount)
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)
finally:
    if (sqliteConnection):
        sqliteConnection.close()
        print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

Output:

> > > Successfully Connected to SQLite
> > >
> > > Record inserted successfully into SqliteDb_developers table  1
> > >
> > > The SQLite connection is closed

---

**Step 3: Query DB**

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("SQLite_Python.db")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM SqliteDb_developers")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
  print(row)

conn.close()
```

Output:

> > > (1, 'Python', 'MakesYou@Fly.com', '2020-01-01', 1000)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. See what tables are there.

```
"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"
```

Comment: filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'",con) 
print(filtered_data) giving me "Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name]
Index: []"

Comment: So it can read a table, but the table is empty. You can now try to make sure there is a Reviews table with correct data in the sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

give similar sharable id to your database file just like you did with Reviews.csv

database_file=drive.CreateFile({'id':'your_sharable_id for sqlite file'})
database_file.GetContentFile('database.sqlite')

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the files from your google drive, you need to mount the drive first:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

After you do this, right click on the file that you intend to read in colab session and select 'Copy Path'and paste it in the connection string.

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/content/database.sqlite')
```

You can now read the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
con = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score !=3",con)
```

If you are executing it twice you will definitely end with this type of error.Execute it exactly once without any fail.

If you get any error then remove

> database.sqlite

this file and extract it again.This time execute it again without any fail/error .This worked for me .