# How to change working directory in file-explorer UI in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colab has a file-explorer UI pane on the left side.

How do I change the file-explorer on the left to simply "go down" into a folder?!?!?!?!?!?!

Or, how do I change the working directory in the file-explorer UI in Google Colab?

I can't find any relevant buttons or menu options. Nothing happens when I run the console command `!cd /content`.
I've tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298146/changing-directory-in-google-colab-breaking-out-of-the-python-interpreter) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50479576/google-colab-changing-directory?rq=1) answers, to no avail. When I run `%cd /content`, the working directory of the *console* changes, but not the file explorer.

For example, suppose I accidentally click this button...

[image: Oops]

Now, my working directory is severely bloated, and it's not at all obvious that my previous directory is `/content/`.

[image: Arrrrggggghhh!]

How do I change it back?

Comment: Have you tried double clicking on the content folder?

Comment: No effect for me. I should clarify that I am able to access the child files.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Facing the same issue

Comment: No. I should clarify that I can access the child files, but I can't change the largest directory. Although I guess you could always restart the runtime. (But then again you lose all the stuff in memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it in UI other then refresh but below worked.

```py
from google.colab import files
files.view('<dir path>')
```

Answer (score 5):

Refreshing the page works for me.