# finding path in google colab

Tags: path, google-colaboratory

I am learning to work on google colab. For some reason, I did cd enter.

Now when I do !pwd

output : `/root`

when I do: `ls!`

output: `googleplay`

This is a file I was supposed to create in another folder.

Now I am not able to figure out how to get into the folder that I have in colab.
I am trying to go to the folder called tutorial that I have in colab.
I don't know how to get to this location

This is the tree structure of my directory

-Sample_data

-tutorial

- tutorial

I know these files are stored in the content folder. But how should I find path to this

Comment: are you asking for a way to get the directory of a specific file when you input the file name itself?

Comment: so currently I am in root directory of google collab but I need to access the content directory. The root and content directory are in same level and I cannot go further back than root directory

Comment: To be more precise there bin, content, root and many directories. While I was using content directotry. When I did cd command I reached inside root directory. Now I am not able to figure out how to move to content directory from root.

Answer (score 0):

```
%cd <directoryname>
```

This is a magic function to change the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question was already answered here: [Changing directory in Google colab (breaking out of the python interpreter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298146/changing-directory-in-google-colab-breaking-out-of-the-python-interpreter)

As the thread suggests, use:

> `%cd DIRECTORY_NAME`

I hope this will help.